# SBT Unresolved Dependency Error - Elasticsearch Test Framework in a Scala Project

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, sbt, nexus

I am doing a Scala project, built with SBT and trying to follow the documentation in:

Elasticsearch website, about their test framework: **https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/using-elasticsearch-test-classes.html**

There, they talk about using the same versions of ES, which in my case would be ES: `2.2.0`  and lucene: `5.4.1`

However, I am not able to build my project, due to dependencies issues with the test framework artifact and version.

I have added:

```
"org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "2.2.0"
```

But SBT fails with:

```
    Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] 
Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ... [info] Resolving io.spray#spray-
json_2.12;1.3.2 ... [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-
testkit_2.12;10.0.1 ... [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-stream-
testkit_2.12;2.4.16 ... [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-
testkit_2.12;2.4.16 ... [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.1 ... [warn] 
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::      
    UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   :: 
org.elasticsearch.test#framework;2.2.0: not found [warn]    
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]  [warn]   Note: 
Unresolved dependencies path: [warn]    
    org.elasticsearch.test:framework:2.2.0 
(/Users/filipemiranda/datawerks/scala-query-engine/build.sbt#L13-30) 
[warn]        +- default:scala-query-engine_2.12:1.0 [trace] Stack trace 
suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output. [trace] Stack trace 
suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output. 
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
org.elasticsearch.test#framework;2.2.0: not found [error] 
(*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
org.elasticsearch.test#framework;2.2.0: not found [error] Total time: 6 s,
 completed Jan 21, 2017 8:20:44 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a 
href="/Users/filipemiranda/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.1/sbt.last.log">/Users/
filipemiranda/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.1/sbt.last.log</a>
```

I ave looked at: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/elasticsearch/test/framework/

And I did not find the same version there.

Has anyone faced similar issues, how to solve this?

Here is my entire **build.sbt**

```
name := "project-name"

version := "1.0"

lazy val scalaV = "2.12.1"
scalaVersion := scalaV
lazy val akkaHttpV = "10.0.1"
lazy val esVersion = "2.2.0"
lazy val luceneVersion = "5.4.1"
lazy val scalatestV = "3.0.1"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaV,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatestV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % akkaHttpV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpV,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.16",
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.8.2" % "test",
  "io.searchbox" % "jest" % "2.0.3",
  "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.2.0" withSources,
  "com.twitter" %% "util-eval" % "6.40.0",


  "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-test-framework" % "5.4.1",
  "org.elasticsearch.test" % "framework" % "2.2.0",
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.8.2" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % akkaHttpV % "test"
)
```

**How can I work this around???**